# my simple code for linked list seems to be wrong but i dont know where is the error of this code

Tags: c

my link list code is printing blank for string and 0 for integer. can someone explain the error in this simple code? thank you in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct data{
 char name[100];
 char type[100];
 int quantity;
 int price;
 struct data *next;
} *head = NULL , *tail = NULL;

int flag = 0;

struct data *newData (char name[] , char type[] , int quantity , int price ){
 struct data *curr = (struct data*) malloc (sizeof (struct data*));
 strcpy(curr->name, name);
 strcpy(curr->type, type);
 curr->quantity   = quantity;
 curr->price      = price;
 curr->next = NULL;
 return curr;
}
```

Insert Function :

```
void insert(char name[] , char type[] , int quantity , int price){
 struct data  *hold;
 struct data *temp  = newData(name, type, quantity, price);
 flag++;

 if(head==NULL){
    head = temp;
    head->next = NULL;
    return;
}

hold = head;
while(hold->next != NULL){
    hold = hold->next;
}
 hold -> next = temp;
 temp -> next = NULL;
}
```

print function :

```
void printAll(){
struct data *ptr = head;
while(ptr!=NULL){
    printf("name : %s\n" , ptr->name);
    printf("type : %s\n", ptr->type);
    printf("quantity : %d\n" , ptr->quantity);
    printf("price : %d\n" , ptr->price);
    ptr = ptr->next;
 }
}
```

Main function :

```
 int main(){
  int q1 = 24;
  int h1 = 19000;
  char n1[100] = "americano";
  char n4[100] = "yes";
  insert(n1, n4, 200, 20000);

  printAll();


  return 0;
 }
```

the output :

```
name : americano
type :
quantity : 0
price : 0
```

sometimes in output "type : " section, it can print "yes" and "*blank*".

Answer (score 2):

In `newData` you're not allocating enough memory:

```
struct data *curr = (struct data*) malloc (sizeof (struct data*));
```

Instead of allocating enough memory for a `struct data`, you're allocating space for a *pointer* to `struct data`.  This is smaller than the size of the struct, so when you attempt to write to it you write past the bounds of the allocated memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the size passed to `malloc` to reflect the struct size, not the pointer size.

```
struct data *curr = malloc (sizeof (struct data));
```

Comment: do you mean i need to change my malloc section into:


`struct data *curr = malloc (sizeof (struct data));`

Comment: @abrakadabra Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: but it becomes an error that says :
`invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'data*' [-fpermissive]`    how about this ??

Comment: @abrakadabra You're compiling with a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler.  Make sure the file has a `.c` extension, and if on Linux use gcc instead of g++.

Comment: @abrakadabra Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.